# C++ like partial specialization in Haskell instance declarations

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Int

class At c v i | c -> v, c -> i where
  at :: c -> i -> v

instance At [a] a Int where
  at l i = l !! i

{--  
f = at [2 ^ i | i <- [0..]] 10

main = print f
--}
```

If I load this in ghci (ghc 7.4.1 with -fglasgow-exts), I get an error like this.

```
Prelude> :load Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, interpreted )

Main.hs:6:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `At [a] a Int'
      (the Coverage Condition fails for one of the functional dependencies;
       Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
    In the instance declaration for `At [a] a Int'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am just learning about functional dependencies.

Comment: The `i -> c` bit says that knowing `i` tells you what `c` is, but then you say that if `i ~ Int` then `c ~ [a]` for any `a`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  That solved the problem.

Comment: zrb: `-fglasgow-exts` is deprecated; instead, you can put `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}` in the beginning of the file.

Comment: @dave4420 -- your comment seemed to resolve this. you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

As dave4420 wrote in the comments: "The `i -> c` bit says that knowing i tells you what `c` is, but then you say that if `i ~ Int` then `c ~ [a]` for any a".